# iTextSharp- putting phrase and table on a single line

Tags: c#, itext

In itextsharp I'm generating a pdf featuring a table- inside this table is a row that should contain a text string, then another nested table. With the inner table having a border.

```
        Font nameFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10);
        PdfPTable pdfpTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        pdfpTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        pdfpTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;
        pdfpTable.TotalWidth = 250f;
        pdfpTable.LockedWidth = true;
        PdfPCell pdfpCell;

        var vouchertable = new PdfPTable(11);
        vouchertable.TotalWidth = 100f;
        vouchertable.LockedWidth = true;
        var tableBorder = Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER | Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER;
        var code = "10162/00012";
        foreach (var s in code)
        {
            var vouchercell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(s.ToString(), nameFont));
            vouchercell.Border = tableBorder;
            vouchercell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            vouchertable.AddCell(vouchercell);
        }
        vouchertable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

        var chunk = new Chunk("Referral Code: ", nameFont);
        pdfpCell = new PdfPCell();
        pdfpCell.AddElement(chunk);
        pdfpCell.AddElement(vouchertable);
        pdfpTable.AddCell(pdfpCell);
```

The 'Referral Code' chunk and the numbers in the boxes (which is an inner table) need to be on the same line, but I can't work out how to not add a newline.

[image: output]
<sub>(source: [oozamaflips.net](http://oozamaflips.net/dev/images/293.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create the main `PdfPTable` with two `PdfPCell`s instead of one and explicitly set each cell's properties:

```
PdfPTable pdfpTable = new PdfPTable(2);

// your code above

pdfpTable.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Referral Code: ", nameFont))
{
    Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,
    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
};
pdfpTable.AddCell(cell);
cell = new PdfPCell(vouchertable) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER };
pdfpTable.AddCell(cell);
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: This is 'sort of' the answer- 'sort of' because the real solution has some extra rows in so I can't use two cell sin the original table- what I can do is make a table with two cells and nest it inside the main table- which works brilliantly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To Generate, Alignment, Table PDF to use following code

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw;

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,43,43, 43, 43);

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"D:\abc\text.pdf", FileMode.Create));


PdfPCell cell = null;
PdfPTable table = null;

document.Open();


Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());


Paragraph para = new Paragraph();

table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.TotalWidth = 340f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("SCHEME INSTALLMENT RECEIPT ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);

cell.Colspan = 1;
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
table.AddCell(cell);

document.Add(table);

Phrase ph1 = new Phrase();
Paragraph mm = new Paragraph();
ph1.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Name           : " + name,FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));
ph1.Add(glue);
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Bill No. :   " + BillNo, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

ph1.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Address      : " + address, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));
ph1.Add(glue);
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Bill Date : " + billDate, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

ph1.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Mobile No.  : " + mobile, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));
ph1.Add(glue);
ph1.Add(new Chunk("Scheme No. : " + orderNo, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

mm.Add(ph1);
para.Add(mm);
document.Add(para);




table = new PdfPTable(3);

table.TotalWidth = 340f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("HSN Code ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("No of Installment", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("Installment Amount", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);

cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
table.AddCell(cell);



table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase("7113", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(paidNo, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
table.AddCell(PhraseCell(new Phrase(paidAmount, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));

cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(), PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.PaddingBottom = 10f;
table.AddCell(cell);




PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
contentByte.MoveTo(45.0, 627.0);
contentByte.LineTo(550.0, 627.0);

document.Add(table);



Paragraph para1 = new Paragraph();
Phrase ph2 = new Phrase();
Paragraph mm1 = new Paragraph();
string amountWord = ConvertNumbertoWords(Convert.ToInt64(paidAmount));
ph2.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph2.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph2.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph2.Add(new Chunk(amountWord + " Only", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

ph2.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph2.Add(new Chunk("By Cash", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

ph2.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph2.Add(new Chunk(paidAmount, FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

mm1.Add(ph2);
para1.Add(mm1);
document.Add(para1);

Paragraph para3 = new Paragraph();
Phrase ph3 = new Phrase();
Paragraph mm3 = new Paragraph();

ph3.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));


ph3.Add(new Chunk("Credit Card Charges :", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

ph3.Add(new Chunk(Environment.NewLine));
ph3.Add(new Chunk("Customer Sign.", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));
ph3.Add(glue);
ph3.Add(new Chunk("For Example", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10,1)));

mm3.Add(ph3);
para3.Add(mm3);
document.Add(para3);

document.Close();
```

Comment: Where exactly are you *putting phrase and table on a single line* as the question asks for?

Comment: ph1.Add(new chunk);    ph1.Add(glue);    ph1.Add(new chunk);  ---when use ph1.Add(glue);